# fill array with different objects from database

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array and try to fill this array with objects from my database. Up until now this way was working

```
var array: ArrayList<MyObject>()

val itemsToFillArray: List<MyObject> = documentSnapshots.toObjects(MyObject::class.java)
array.addAll(itemsToFillArray)
```

But my problem now is, that I have multiple objects in my database and not just `MyObject`. I already gave my objects an Interface and tried it this way, but its not working. 
How can I retrieve different objects from my database and store them in my array?

Comment: There is a similar thread where this issue was solved, it's also with firestore and kotlin using ArrayList https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647028/get-array-of-object-from-firestore

Comment: What is the type of `documentSnapshots`? How do you retrieve the data? Ever considered using JPA, which will convert objects for you? This question has too many unknown variables

Answer (score 1):

> I already gave my objects an Interface.

Let's assume you use interface `MyInterface`:

```
interface MyInterface { /* ... */ }
```

In this case `MyObject` class and other classes you want to use should implement this interface:

```
class MyObject : MyInterface { /* ... */ }

class MyOtherObject : MyInterface { /* ... */ }
```

If you do it correctly then you should be able to store different objects in the array:

```
val array: ArrayList<MyInterface> = arrayListOf()

val itemsToFillArray1: List<MyObject> = documentSnapshots1.toObjects(MyObject::class.java)
val itemsToFillArray2: List<MyOtherObject> = documentSnapshots2.toObjects(MyOtherObject::class.java)
array.addAll(itemsToFillArray1)
array.addAll(itemsToFillArray2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of declairing specific object `MyObject` you can declair as `Any`.

```
var array: ArrayList<Any>() = null
```

But while adding the items you need to add check for allowed objects, so that any unknown object will not get assigned to the array.

```
if(documentSnapshots.documents is MyObject || 
      documentSnapshots.documents is MyObjectTwo){
     array.add(documentSnapshots.documents)
}
```

Comment: Ok I see thank you, but how would I then fill the objects from the database into my array?
Like this `val items: List<Any> = documentSnapshots.documents`?

Comment: This is not much of an answer unchecked casting is unsafe. And filling unknown values is not the best idea.

Comment: What do you recommend then @AnimeshSahu ?

Comment: @DurgaM there is no `instanceof` in kotlin, there is `is` keyword. And I don't understand what you are trying to show in your answer, you are overwriting the variable.